# Can I find the pixels of tiff file for given lat long if I have this information?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-python-binding

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: correctly_merged.tif
Size is 44835, 26402
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (13.159040050633186,11.913294314323917)
Pixel Size = (0.000003210050390,-0.000003210074723)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  13.1590401,  11.9132943) ( 13d 9'32.54"E, 11d54'47.86"N)
Lower Left  (  13.1590401,  11.8285419) ( 13d 9'32.54"E, 11d49'42.75"N)
Upper Right (  13.3029627,  11.9132943) ( 13d18'10.67"E, 11d54'47.86"N)
Lower Right (  13.3029627,  11.8285419) ( 13d18'10.67"E, 11d49'42.75"N)
Center      (  13.2310014,  11.8709181) ( 13d13'51.60"E, 11d52'15.31"N)
Band 1 Block=44835x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=44835x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=44835x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

I found this answer in JAVA but I cannot understand it.
Anyone who can tell me in python?

[Convert latitude longitude pair to pixels in geotiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245472/convert-latitude-longitude-pair-to-pixels-in-geotiff/245653)

Comment: maybe this helps: https://gist.github.com/stefanocudini/5201689

Comment: gdallocationinfo can also do it from the command line: http://www.gdal.org/gdallocationinfo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can.  I like to use [geoio](https://github.com/DigitalGlobe/geoio) for this kind of stuff.

```
import geoio
filename = ... # filename of the image
img = geoio.GeoImage(filename)
xPixel, yPixel = img.proj_to_raster(lon, lat)
```

Will do it.  You can also go in the other direction with their `raster_to_proj` method.