# Using GDAL and OSR to convert from latitude/longitude to DEM coordinates

Tags: gdal, osr

I'm trying to convert back and for between DEM and "world" (aka latitude/longitude) coordinates using GDAL and I think I might be misunderstanding something which is causing me to get "wrong" answers when trying to go from world to DEM coordinates.  I have the following MWE which demonstrates the problem:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    file = "./WAC_EMP_643NM_E300S2250_304P.IMG"
    data: gdal.Dataset = gdal.Open(file)
   
    # first check that we can transform from DEM coordinates to lat/lon 
    proj_crs: osr.SpatialReference = data.GetSpatialRef()
    
    latlon_crs = osr.SpatialReference()
    latlon_crs.CopyGeogCSFrom(proj_crs)
    
    transform_proj_to_latlon: osr.CoordinateTransformation = osr.CreateCoordinateTransformation(proj_crs, latlon_crs)
    
    gt_from_map = data.GetGeoTransform()
    
    # check the bounds of the map.  Lat should be between -60 and 0 and lon should be between 180 and 270 (180 and -90) per https://pds.lroc.asu.edu/data/LRO-L-LROC-5-RDR-V1.0/LROLRC_2001/DATA/MDR/WAC_EMP/WAC_EMP_README.TXT
    min_lat, min_lon = transform_proj_to_latlon.TransformPoint(*gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_from_map, 0, 0))[:2]
    max_lat, max_lon = transform_proj_to_latlon.TransformPoint(*gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_from_map, data.RasterXSize, data.RasterYSize))[:2]
    print(f"{min_lat=}, {max_lat=}, expected = [-60, 0]")
    print(f"{min_lon=}, {max_lon=}, expected = [180, 270(-90)]")
    
    # check the inverse transform from lat/lon to dem coordinates
    transform_latlon_to_proj: osr.CoordinateTransformation = osr.CreateCoordinateTransformation(latlon_crs, proj_crs)
    gt_to_map = gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt_from_map)
    
    minx, miny = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_to_map, *transform_latlon_to_proj.TransformPoint(min_lat, min_lon)[:2])
    maxx, maxy = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_to_map, *transform_latlon_to_proj.TransformPoint(max_lat, max_lon)[:2])
    
    print(f"{minx=}, {maxx=}, expected = [0, {data.RasterXSize}]")
    print(f"{miny=}, {maxy=}, expected = [0, {data.RasterYSize}]")
    
    geo_coords_from_map = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_from_map, data.RasterXSize, data.RasterYSize)
    geo_coords_from_latlon = transform_latlon_to_proj.TransformPoint(max_lat, max_lon)[:2]
    print(f"{geo_coords_from_map=}, {geo_coords_from_latlon=}")
```

which, when run with the file from [here](https://pds.lroc.asu.edu/data/LRO-L-LROC-5-RDR-V1.0/LROLRC_2001/DATA/MDR/WAC_EMP/WAC_EMP_643NM_E300S2250_304P.IMG) saved in the working directory produces the following output

```
min_lat=0.0, max_lat=-60.00000000000011, expected = [-60, 0]
min_lon=180.0000000000036, max_lon=-89.99999999999623, expected = [180, 270(-90)]
minx=-4.258225509263292e-12, maxx=-82079.9999999998, expected = [0, 27360]
miny=0.0, maxy=18240.0, expected = [0, 18240]
geo_coords_from_map=[8187304.614520474, -1819401.0254489721], geo_coords_from_latlon=(-2729101.538173339, -1819401.0254489721)
```

Specifically in the output the 3 and 5 lines are wrong.

The fifth line is showing that there is a problem with the coordinate transformation from the "world" to the "projection frame" but I'm not sure how to fix this?

For reference, the expected values for the first 2 lines of the output come from [here](https://pds.lroc.asu.edu/data/LRO-L-LROC-5-RDR-V1.0/LROLRC_2001/DATA/MDR/WAC_EMP/WAC_EMP_README.TXT).

Comment: For reference, I've looked at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245472/convert-latitude-longitude-pair-to-pixels-in-geotiff already which I believe is pretty similar to what I'm doing here, but I'm still getting the wrong answer

Comment: Can't answer why the geog -> projected transform doesn't work, but further up in your code you've forgotten that 0,0 (upper left of image) is min X, *max* Y not min X, min Y because image (pixel) row values increase but map Y coordinates decrease from top to bottom. i.e. `max_lat, min_lon = transform_proj_to_latlon.TransformPoint(*gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_from_map, 0, 0)`

Comment: Possibly because the extent crosses the antimeridian.