# Rotate latitude and longitude coordinates based on True North

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

I have a number of latitude- and longitude coordinates.
In addition, I have two other data sources:

```
trueNorth = 166    # I only know the value
```

and a compass:

[image]

How do I update my coordinates based on this information? I think the following [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/71151) is closely related, but one the inputs are the coordinates of the south pole.
Please explain to me how I can get the south pole coordinates from `trueNorth`.
My knowledge on this area is very limited

Format of the coordinates:

```
29.66150677   -98.39336541
29.66150677   -98.39337576
29.66150651   -98.39336541
29.66150328   -98.39337576
29.66150677   -98.39336475
29.66150677   -98.39338611
29.66150393   -98.39338611
29.66150677   -98.39339646
29.66150659   -98.39339646
29.66150677   -98.39339693
29.66151576   -98.39334472
29.66151576   -98.39335506
29.66151511   -98.39334472
29.66151058   -98.39335506
29.66151576   -98.39334322
29.66151576   -98.39336541
29.66151576   -98.39337576
29.66151576   -98.39338611
29.66151576   -98.39339646
29.66151576   -98.39340681
29.66151067   -98.39340681
29.66151576   -98.39341515
29.66152475   -98.39332402
29.66152475   -98.39333437
29.66152443   -98.39332402
29.66151973   -98.39333437
29.66152475   -98.39332332
29.66152475   -98.39334472
29.66152475   -98.39335506
29.66152475   -98.39336541
29.66152475   -98.39337576
29.66152475   -98.39338611
29.66152475   -98.39339646
29.66152475   -98.39340681
29.66152475   -98.39341716
29.66151699   -98.39341716
29.66152475   -98.39342722
29.66153375   -98.39331367
29.66153375   -98.39332402
29.6615302    -98.39331367
29.66153375   -98.3933086
29.66153375   -98.39333437
29.66153375   -98.39334472
29.66153375   -98.39335506
29.66153375   -98.39336541
29.66153375   -98.39337576
29.66153375   -98.39338611
29.66153375   -98.39339646
29.66153375   -98.39340681
29.66153375   -98.39341716
29.66153375   -98.39342751
29.66152507   -98.39342751
29.66153375   -98.39343443
29.66154274   -98.39330332
29.66154274   -98.39331367
29.66153745   -98.39330332
29.66154274   -98.39329625
29.66154274   -98.39332402
29.66154274   -98.39333437
29.66154274   -98.39334472
29.66154274   -98.39335506
29.66154274   -98.39336541
29.66154274   -98.39337576
29.66154274   -98.39338611
29.66154274   -98.39339646
29.66154274   -98.39340681
29.66154274   -98.39341716
29.66154274   -98.39342751
29.66154274   -98.39343786
29.66153992   -98.39343786
29.66154274   -98.3934387
29.66155173   -98.39329297
29.66155173   -98.39330332
29.6615457    -98.39329297
29.66155173   -98.39328644
29.66155173   -98.39331367
29.66155173   -98.39332402
29.66155173   -98.39333437
29.66155173   -98.39334472
29.66155173   -98.39335506
29.66155173   -98.39336541
29.66155173   -98.39337576
29.66155173   -98.39338611
29.66155173   -98.39339646
29.66155173   -98.39340681
29.66155173   -98.39341716
29.66155173   -98.39342751
29.66155173   -98.39343786
29.66155173   -98.39344106
29.66156073   -98.39328262
29.66156073   -98.39329297
29.66155555   -98.39328262
29.66156073   -98.39327744
29.66156073   -98.39330332
29.66156073   -98.39331367
29.66156073   -98.39332402
29.66156073   -98.39333437
29.66156073   -98.39334472
29.66156073   -98.39335506
29.66156073   -98.39336541
29.66156073   -98.39337576
29.66156073   -98.39338611
29.66156073   -98.39339646
29.66156073   -98.39340681
29.66156073   -98.39341716
29.66156073   -98.39342751
29.66156073   -98.39343786
29.66156073   -98.39344196
29.66156972   -98.39327227
29.66156972   -98.39328262
29.66156651   -98.39327227
29.66156972   -98.39326964
29.66156972   -98.39329297
29.66156972   -98.39330332
29.66156972   -98.39331367
29.66156972   -98.39332402
29.66156972   -98.39333437
29.66156972   -98.39334472
29.66156972   -98.39335506
29.66156972   -98.39336541
29.66156972   -98.39337576
29.66156972   -98.39338611
29.66156972   -98.39339646
29.66156972   -98.39340681
29.66156972   -98.39341716
29.66156972   -98.39342751
29.66156972   -98.39343786
29.66156972   -98.393442
29.66157871   -98.39327227
29.66157871   -98.39328262
29.66157871   -98.39326327
29.66157871   -98.39329297
29.66157871   -98.39330332
29.66157871   -98.39331367
29.66157871   -98.39332402
29.66157871   -98.39333437
29.66157871   -98.39334472
29.66157871   -98.39335506
29.66157871   -98.39336541
29.66157871   -98.39337576
29.66157871   -98.39338611
29.66157871   -98.39339646
29.66157871   -98.39340681
29.66157871   -98.39341716
29.66157871   -98.39342751
29.66157871   -98.39343786
29.66157871   -98.39344084
29.66158771   -98.39326192
29.66158771   -98.39327227
29.66158097   -98.39326192
29.66158771   -98.39325788
29.66158771   -98.39328262
29.66158771   -98.39329297
29.66158771   -98.39330332
29.66158771   -98.39331367
29.66158771   -98.39332402
29.66158771   -98.39333437
29.66158771   -98.39334472
29.66158771   -98.39335506
29.66158771   -98.39336541
29.66158771   -98.39337576
29.66158771   -98.39338611
29.66158771   -98.39339646
29.66158771   -98.39340681
29.66158771   -98.39341716
29.66158771   -98.39342751
29.66158771   -98.39343786
29.66158771   -98.39343926
29.66159226   -98.39343786
29.6615967    -98.39326192
29.6615967    -98.39327227
29.6615967    -98.39325426
29.6615967    -98.39328262
29.6615967    -98.39329297
29.6615967    -98.39330332
29.6615967    -98.39331367
29.6615967    -98.39332402
29.6615967    -98.39333437
29.6615967    -98.39334472
29.6615967    -98.39335506
29.6615967    -98.39336541
29.6615967    -98.39337576
29.6615967    -98.39338611
29.6615967    -98.39339646
29.6615967    -98.39340681
29.6615967    -98.39341716
29.6615967    -98.39342751
29.6615967    -98.39343623
29.66160569   -98.39325157
29.66160569   -98.39326192
29.66160564   -98.39325157
29.66160569   -98.39325156
29.66160569   -98.39327227
29.66160569   -98.39328262
29.66160569   -98.39329297
29.66160569   -98.39330332
29.66160569   -98.39331367
29.66160569   -98.39332402
29.66160569   -98.39333437
29.66160569   -98.39334472
29.66160569   -98.39335506
29.66160569   -98.39336541
29.66160569   -98.39337576
29.66160569   -98.39338611
29.66160569   -98.39339646
29.66160569   -98.39340681
29.66160569   -98.39341716
29.66160569   -98.39342751
29.66160569   -98.39343291
29.66161468   -98.39325157
29.66161468   -98.39326192
29.66161468   -98.39324921
29.66161468   -98.39327227
29.66161468   -98.39328262
29.66161468   -98.39329297
29.66161468   -98.39330332
29.66161468   -98.39331367
29.66161468   -98.39332402
29.66161468   -98.39333437
29.66161468   -98.39334472
29.66161468   -98.39335506
29.66161468   -98.39336541
29.66161468   -98.39337576
29.66161468   -98.39338611
29.66161468   -98.39339646
29.66161468   -98.39340681
29.66161468   -98.39341716
29.66161468   -98.39342751
29.66161468   -98.39342823
29.66161592   -98.39342751
29.66162368   -98.39325157
29.66162368   -98.39326192
29.66162368   -98.39324697
29.66162368   -98.39327227
29.66162368   -98.39328262
29.66162368   -98.39329297
29.66162368   -98.39330332
29.66162368   -98.39331367
29.66162368   -98.39332402
29.66162368   -98.39333437
29.66162368   -98.39334472
29.66162368   -98.39335506
29.66162368   -98.39336541
29.66162368   -98.39337576
29.66162368   -98.39338611
29.66162368   -98.39339646
29.66162368   -98.39340681
29.66162368   -98.39341716
29.66162368   -98.39342302
29.66163267   -98.39325157
29.66163267   -98.39326192
29.66163267   -98.39324642
29.66163267   -98.39327227
29.66163267   -98.39328262
29.66163267   -98.39329297
29.66163267   -98.39330332
29.66163267   -98.39331367
29.66163267   -98.39332402
29.66163267   -98.39333437
29.66163267   -98.39334472
29.66163267   -98.39335506
29.66163267   -98.39336541
29.66163267   -98.39337576
29.66163267   -98.39338611
29.66163267   -98.39339646
29.66163267   -98.39340681
29.66163267   -98.39341716
29.66163267   -98.39341722
29.66163275   -98.39341716
29.66164166   -98.39325157
29.66164166   -98.39326192
29.66164166   -98.39324588
29.66164166   -98.39327227
29.66164166   -98.39328262
29.66164166   -98.39329297
29.66164166   -98.39330332
29.66164166   -98.39331367
29.66164166   -98.39332402
29.66164166   -98.39333437
29.66164166   -98.39334472
29.66164166   -98.39335506
29.66164166   -98.39336541
29.66164166   -98.39337576
29.66164166   -98.39338611
29.66164166   -98.39339646
29.66164166   -98.39340681
29.66164166   -98.39341103
29.66164749   -98.39340681
29.66165066   -98.39325157
29.66165066   -98.39326192
29.66165066   -98.39324533
29.66165066   -98.39327227
29.66165066   -98.39328262
29.66165066   -98.39329297
29.66165066   -98.39330332
29.66165066   -98.39331367
29.66165066   -98.39332402
29.66165066   -98.39333437
29.66165066   -98.39334472
29.66165066   -98.39335506
29.66165066   -98.39336541
29.66165066   -98.39337576
29.66165066   -98.39338611
29.66165066   -98.39339646
29.66165066   -98.39340447
29.66165965   -98.39325157
29.66165965   -98.39326192
29.66165965   -98.39324479
29.66165965   -98.39327227
29.66165965   -98.39328262
29.66165965   -98.39329297
29.66165965   -98.39330332
29.66165965   -98.39331367
29.66165965   -98.39332402
29.66165965   -98.39333437
29.66165965   -98.39334472
29.66165965   -98.39335506
29.66165965   -98.39336541
29.66165965   -98.39337576
29.66165965   -98.39338611
29.66165965   -98.39339646
29.66165965   -98.39339783
29.6616615    -98.39339646
29.66166864   -98.39325157
29.66166864   -98.39326192
29.66166864   -98.39324424
29.66166864   -98.39327227
29.66166864   -98.39328262
29.66166864   -98.39329297
29.66166864   -98.39330332
29.66166864   -98.39331367
29.66166864   -98.39332402
29.66166864   -98.39333437
29.66166864   -98.39334472
29.66166864   -98.39335506
29.66166864   -98.39336541
29.66166864   -98.39337576
29.66166864   -98.39338611
29.66166864   -98.39339119
29.66167552   -98.39338611
29.66167764   -98.39325157
29.66167764   -98.39326192
29.66167764   -98.3932437
29.66167764   -98.39327227
29.66167764   -98.39328262
29.66167764   -98.39329297
29.66167764   -98.39330332
29.66167764   -98.39331367
29.66167764   -98.39332402
29.66167764   -98.39333437
29.66167764   -98.39334472
29.66167764   -98.39335506
29.66167764   -98.39336541
29.66167764   -98.39337576
29.66167764   -98.39338455
29.66168663   -98.39325157
29.66168663   -98.39326192
29.66168663   -98.39324315
29.66168663   -98.39327227
29.66168663   -98.39328262
29.66168663   -98.39329297
29.66168663   -98.39330332
29.66168663   -98.39331367
29.66168663   -98.39332402
29.66168663   -98.39333437
29.66168663   -98.39334472
29.66168663   -98.39335506
29.66168663   -98.39336541
29.66168663   -98.39337576
29.66168663   -98.39337791
29.66168954   -98.39337576
29.66169562   -98.39325157
29.66169562   -98.39326192
29.66169562   -98.39324277
29.66169562   -98.39327227
29.66169562   -98.39328262
29.66169562   -98.39329297
29.66169562   -98.39330332
29.66169562   -98.39331367
29.66169562   -98.39332402
29.66169562   -98.39333437
29.66169562   -98.39334472
29.66169562   -98.39335506
29.66169562   -98.39336541
29.66169562   -98.39337127
29.66170356   -98.39336541
29.66170462   -98.39325157
29.66170462   -98.39326192
29.66170462   -98.39324245
29.66170462   -98.39327227
29.66170462   -98.39328262
29.66170462   -98.39329297
29.66170462   -98.39330332
29.66170462   -98.39331367
29.66170462   -98.39332402
29.66170462   -98.39333437
29.66170462   -98.39334472
29.66170462   -98.39335506
29.66170462   -98.39336463
29.66171361   -98.39325157
29.66171361   -98.39326192
29.66171361   -98.39324213
29.66171361   -98.39327227
29.66171361   -98.39328262
29.66171361   -98.39329297
29.66171361   -98.39330332
29.66171361   -98.39331367
29.66171361   -98.39332402
29.66171361   -98.39333437
29.66171361   -98.39334472
29.66171361   -98.39335506
29.66171361   -98.39335799
29.66171758   -98.39335506
29.6617226    -98.39325157
29.6617226    -98.39326192
29.6617226    -98.393242
29.6617226    -98.39327227
29.6617226    -98.39328262
29.6617226    -98.39329297
29.6617226    -98.39330332
29.6617226    -98.39331367
29.6617226    -98.39332402
29.6617226    -98.39333437
29.6617226    -98.39334472
29.6617226    -98.39335135
29.66173159   -98.39334472
29.6617316    -98.39325157
29.6617316    -98.39326192
29.6617316    -98.393242
29.6617316    -98.39327227
29.6617316    -98.39328262
29.6617316    -98.39329297
29.6617316    -98.39330332
29.6617316    -98.39331367
29.6617316    -98.39332402
29.6617316    -98.39333437
29.6617316    -98.39334471
29.66174059   -98.39325157
29.66174059   -98.39326192
29.66174059   -98.393242
29.66174059   -98.39327227
29.66174059   -98.39328262
29.66174059   -98.39329297
29.66174059   -98.39330332
29.66174059   -98.39331367
29.66174059   -98.39332402
29.66174059   -98.39333437
29.66174059   -98.39333807
29.66174561   -98.39333437
29.66174958   -98.39325157
29.66174958   -98.39326192
29.66174958   -98.39324293
29.66174958   -98.39327227
29.66174958   -98.39328262
29.66174958   -98.39329297
29.66174958   -98.39330332
29.66174958   -98.39331367
29.66174958   -98.39332402
29.66174958   -98.39333143
29.66175858   -98.39325157
29.66175858   -98.39326192
29.66176663   -98.39325157
29.66176757   -98.39326192
29.66175858   -98.39324585
29.66175858   -98.39327227
29.66175858   -98.39328262
29.66175858   -98.39329297
29.66175858   -98.39330332
29.66175858   -98.39331367
29.66175858   -98.39332402
29.66175858   -98.39332427
29.6617589    -98.39332402
29.66176757   -98.39327227
29.66177412   -98.39326192
29.66177656   -98.39327227
29.66176757   -98.3932525
29.66176757   -98.39328262
29.66176757   -98.39329297
29.66176757   -98.39330332
29.66176757   -98.39331367
29.66177543   -98.39330332
29.66176974   -98.39331367
29.66176757   -98.3933162
29.66177656   -98.39328262
29.66177775   -98.39327227
29.66177872   -98.39328262
29.66177656   -98.39326599
29.66177656   -98.39329297
29.66177855   -98.39329297
29.66177656   -98.39330028
```

screenshot of coordinates where `trueNorth = 0` and `trueNorth = 166`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNTUl.jpg

Comment: What is the format of your other source? Is it an image? A list of points? Do you know the projection? Are you familiar with proj4?

Comment: I added the data format, it's a simple txt-file. I don't know `proj4`. I used the `utm`-module to transform the longlat coordinates to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I checked your coordinate list: these are spot on the green of San Antonio TX golf course, so there is no need to change the coordinates. Where do you want to use them for, as the green is well mapped in openstreetmap? https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/769381482

Comment: correct.  Can you explain to me how the value of `166` for `trueNorth` is related/calculated?

Comment: This north arrow is placed on an almost upside-down map of the golf course. It is useful on a map, and if you need to reproduce that same map using your coordinate list.

Comment: So what do you want to do with your coordinate list?

Comment: If possible, I want to display the coordinates based on the `trueNorth` angle. I added two screenshots.

Comment: You want to display your coordinates on the first map image you provided? In other words, you want to rotate your coordinates so that north no longer points straight up?

Comment: @barrycarter yes, exactly. So I want to display it like the second image where north is longer located straight up

Comment: You could always "cheat" and rotate your original image so that north is up, plot your points, and then rotate back to the original rotation. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178354/convert-lat-lng-to-pixel-and-vice-versa provides some guidance on how to do this